# Query Web Table on Current Website

Tags: vba, excel, csv

I am running into a bit of a problem. Normally when I pull a table I use the "data from web" tool in excel, however I now have quite a few places I need to pull data that first require me to enter a username and password. I figured out some code for that (though probably not the most elegant) but realized that once I get to my desired page I have no idea how to extract the table. Here is what I have so far.

```
Sub Login()
    Sheets("IOL").Select
    Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.application")
    ie.Visible = True
    ie.Navigate ("https://internalsite.company.com/secure/login" & ActiveCell)
    Do
        If ie.ReadyState = 4 Then
            ie.Visible = True
            Exit Do
        Else
            DoEvents
        End If
    Loop
    ie.Document.forms(0).all("badgeBarcodeId").Value = "00000"
    ie.Document.forms(0).submit
'used because it redirects to a new page after submitting and I couldn't figure out how to make it wait for the new page to load before proceeding. 
    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:02"))
    ie.Document.forms(0).all("password").Value = "00000"
    ie.Document.forms(0).submit
End Sub
```

After the login is accomplished I would like to go to http://internalsite.company.com/csv and import the csv directly into a sheet. Anytime I make a new connection it makes me log in again so I figure there has to be a way to extract the file without adding a new connection. I'm pretty new with more complex VBA so bear with me.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get this code to do the job, but it is more preferable to get the CSV directly instead of the table. Sometimes the table doesn't like to load.

```
 Sub Login()
        Dim clip As DataObject
        Dim ieTable As Object
        Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.application")
        ie.Visible = True
        ie.Navigate ("https://internalsite1.company.com/secure/login" & ActiveCell)
        Do
            If ie.ReadyState = 4 Then
                ie.Visible = True
                Exit Do
            Else
                DoEvents
            End If
        Loop
        ie.Document.forms(0).all("badgeBarcodeId").Value = "00000"
        ie.Document.forms(0).submit
        Do While ie.Busy: DoEvents: Loop
        Do Until ie.ReadyState = 4: DoEvents: Loop
        ie.Document.forms(0).all("password").Value = "000000"
        ie.Document.forms(0).submit
        Do While ie.Busy: DoEvents: Loop
        Do Until ie.ReadyState = 4: DoEvents: Loop
        ie.Navigate "http://internalsite2.company.com/site/Inbound?filter=1To3Days"
        Do While ie.Busy: DoEvents: Loop
        Do Until ie.ReadyState = 4: DoEvents: Loop
        Set ieTable = ie.Document.all.Item("DataTables_Table_0")
        If Not ieTable Is Nothing Then
        Set clip = New DataObject
        clip.SetText "" & ieTable.outerHTML & ""
        clip.PutInClipboard
        Workbooks("Production Meeting Dashboard.xlsm").Activate
        Sheets("IOL").Select
        Range("A1").Select
        ActiveSheet.PasteSpecial Format:="Unicode Text", link:=False, _
            DisplayAsIcon:=False, NoHTMLFormatting:=True
         End If
    End Sub
```